# Inject Failing using "WithParameters" Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm trying to register some endpoints I've created, however, Autofac is throwing an exception, saying I haven't registered my `BControl` class. Here is my registration code:

```
    builder.RegisterType<GControlEndpoint>().As<IBusConsumer>().SingleInstance();
    builder.RegisterType<BControlEndpoint>().As<IBusConsumer>().SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterType<BSControlEndpoint>().As<IBusConsumer>().SingleInstance()
      .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "bControlEndpoint",
        (pi, c) => c.Resolve<BControlEndpoint>())
      .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "gControlEndpoint",
        (pi, c) => c.Resolve<GControlEndpoint>());
```

And my `BSControlEndpoint` code is as follows:

```
  private BControlEndpoint bControlEndpoint;
  private GControlEndpoint gControlEndpoint;

  public BSControlEndpoint(
    BControlEndpoint bControlEndpoint,
    GControlEndpoint gControlEndpoint)
  {
    this.bControlEndpoint = bControlEndpoint;
    this.gControlEndpoint = gControlEndpoint;
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Autofac error is :

`Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'Sa.BControlEndpoint' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.`

Comment: Yes it's real code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `AsSelf` to the registration definition of dependencies:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<GControlEndpoint>()
   .As<IBusConsumer>()
   .AsSelf()
   .SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<BControlEndpoint>()
    .As<IBusConsumer>()
    .AsSelf()
    .SingleInstance();
```

Also this should make `WithParameter` call not needed:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<BSControlEndpoint>().As<IBusConsumer>().SingleInstance();
```

Another option is to look into keyed dependencies registration ([docs](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html))

Comment: Argh... thank you. Can't believe I missed the `AsSelf()` bit!!!